# Filling in uninitialized array in java? (or workaround!)

Tags: java, android, opengl-es, inputstream, dynamic-memory-allocation

I'm currently in the process of creating an OBJ importer for an opengles android game. I'm relatively new to the language java, so I'm not exactly clear on a few things.

I have an array which will hold the number of vertices in the model(along with a few other arrays as well):

```
float vertices[];
```

The problem is that I don't know how many vertices there are in the model before I read the file using the inputstream given to me.

Would I be able to fill it in as I need to like this?:

```
vertices[95] = 5.004f; //vertices was defined like the example above
```

or do I have to initialize it beforehand?

if the latter is the case then what would be a good way to find out the number of vertices in the file? Once I read it using inputstreamreader.read() it goes to the next line until it reads the whole file. The only thing I can think of would be to read the whole file, count the number of vertices, then read it AGAIN the fill in the newly initialized array.

Is there a way to dynamically allocate the data as is needed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use an ArrayList which will give you the dynamic size that you need.

```
   List<Float> vertices = new ArrayList<Float>();
```

You can add a value like this:

```
   vertices.add(5.0F);
```

and the list will grow to suit your needs.

Some things to note: The ArrayList will hold objects, not primitive types. So it stores the float values you provide as Float objects. However, it is easy to get the original float value from this.

If you absolutely need an array then after you read in the entire list of values you can easily get an array from the List.

You can start reading about Java Collections [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/implementations/list.html).

Answer (score 1):

In java arrays have to be initialised beforehand. In your case you have the following options:

1) Use an `ArrayList` (or some other implementation of `List` interface), as suggested by others. Such lists can grow dynamically so this will help.

2) If you have control over the file format, add information on the number of vertices to the beginning of the file, so you can pre-initialise your array with correct size.

3) If you don't have control over it, try guessing the number of vertices based on file size (float is 4 bytes, so maybe divide `File.length()` by 4, for example). If the guessed number is too small, you can dynamically create a bigger array (say, 120% of the previous array size), the copy all data from previous array into the new one and carry on. This may be costly but if your guessing of array size is precise it will not be a problem.

We might be able to give you more ideas if you give us more information on file format and/or how this array of vertices going to be used (like: stored for a long time, or thrown away quickly).

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't fill in uninitialized array.
If you need a dynamic structure that allows storing data + indexes (which seem to be important in your case), I would go for Map (key of Map would be your index):

```
Map<Integer, Float> vertices = new HashMap<Integer, Float>();
vertices.put(95, 5.004f);
```